# How to compile Cryptography via setup.py using Cython?

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

My code requires cryptography module
I use Cython to distribute my code, say foo.pyx

I want to perform following task using cryptography

```py
import cryptography.fernet
key = b"My Key"
fer = Fernet(key)
content = input().encode()
fer.encrypt(content)
```

Next, I want to distribute this as .pyd

Again, I don't want users to pip install cryptography on their own pc.
Is there any way to distribute foo.px file as foo.pyd file including Cryptography with it?

My setup.py file is:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("foo.pyx")
)
```

Kindly Note: My platform is Windows 10

Comment: `cryptography` requires some parts to be compiled, which you can do ahead of time and include it in the app you deliver. Look at [building `cryptography` on Windows](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-windows).

Comment: @Lenormju It would be really helpful if you could provide any code.

Comment: It really depends on your environment, which you did not detail at all in your question.

Comment: @Lenormju Kindly note it is windows 10.and I've edited the question as per your advice